# How to use two values to define order in MySQL but priorize one of them?

Tags: mysql

I have  a discussion board with the following table structure:

```
+-------------------------------+
|       TABLE: MESSAGES         |
+-------------------------------+
| id             | int(11)      |
+-------------------------------+
| parent         | int(11)      |
+-------------------------------+
| author         | int(11)      |
+-------------------------------+
| last_reply     | datetime     |
+-------------------------------+
| written        | datetime     |
+-------------------------------+
| title          | varchar(256) |
+-------------------------------+
| content        | text         |
+-------------------------------+
```

The default value for `last_reply` is NULL. If a thread is replied, the `last_reply` of all messages in it will be set to the datetime of the last reply.

What I'm trying to achieve is an order of the conversations where both `last_reply` and `written` will be considered, but where the `last_reply` will be priorized over `written` when available.

So if `last_reply` is available, we use that value for ordering. If not, we use written.

I apologize if this is badly explained.

My best shot so far has been this:

```
SELECT *, COALESCE(last_reply,written) AS tmp FROM messages
WHERE parent = 0 ORDER BY written DESC, tmp DESC
```

This doesn't work correctly.

If you get my point, please guide me to the correct direction :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM messages
WHERE PARENT=0
ORDER BY IFNULL(last_reply,written) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *, COALESCE(last_reply,0) AS with_replay FROM messages
WHERE parent = 0
ORDER BY with_replay DESC,written DESC
```